# Text following pointer dissapears

Tags: javascript

I need a text following the pointer, like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpvaxs65/3/), but the text is dissapearing.

The text is there, if I change the `motion` function like this:

```
function motion(e) {
      const follower = document.getElementById('follower');
      let posicX = e.pageX;
      let posicY = e.pageY + 15;
      follower.style.left = posicX + 'px';
      follower.style.top = posicY + 'px';
};
```

Adding 15 pixels to the Y position it works. The thing is I need to use it without adding any pixel.

I tried switching the `follower` component from `<div>` to `<p>` and `<span>` but unsuccessfully. Any hint on how to solve this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because as soon as `#follower` element appears, your pointer is now over `#follower` and it triggers `onleave(...)` for canvas that is positioned beyond #follower.

What you can do is add `pointer-events: none;` CSS property to #follower style.

`pointer-events` is supported by all modern browsers, so in theory, you should be fine.

```html
<div style="
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: red;
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
        pointer-events:none; <--- !!! NOTICE property here
        margin: 0" id="follower">Hello!!!</div>
```

---

Now, the problem with your approach is that each time you update the element's position it also triggers the browser to recalculate the layout. That is not very efficient. I'd be better if you do something like that

```js
follower.style.transform = `translate(${posicX}px, ${posicY}px)`;
```

---

Now, the best approach would be to render text directly on canvas and modify it as needed.

Comment: Aside: It would also be an improvement to get the `id` of the `follower` element once outside the `motion` function, meaning after the first the load of the page, and then use that, instead of fetching the element every single time